# Stored Procedure calling variables from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that uses a variable ID, I have a list of valid IDs in a table.

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that runs a specific piece of code if the ID exists in table. I'm just not sure of the syntax.

Below is my pseudo-code of what I'm attempting to do.

```
IF
@ID = possible id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [dbo].ID_TABLE WHERE ID = 'valid')
      SELECT * FROM dbo.[results]

ELSE

SELECT * FROM dbo.[otherresults]
```

I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Remove `= possible id` and its valid

Comment: re-write your OP it's quite confusing

Comment: Instead of IF you can use a `UNION` and define the condition in the `WHERE`. It has the advantage of guarante the columns form both queries are the same.

Comment: Can I use IF
@ID = (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [dbo].ID_TABLE WHERE ID = 'valid')
                SELECT * FROM dbo.[results]

Comment: `IF @ID IN` - you need to use `IN` when multiple values are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, this is the case where you would use `EXISTS`; as in....

`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ID_TABLE WHERE ID = @ID)`

While `@ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT` would work, that query requires going through the table data to assemble a result set that is then checked for @ID's inclusion. EXISTS queries do not create result sets, and return early on the first row fitting the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If your query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [dbo].ID_TABLE WHERE ID = 'valid'
```

always returns only one id, then below solution is enough

```
@ID = (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [dbo].ID_TABLE WHERE ID = 'valid')
```

If it returns list of ids, then you need to create a temp table and store those id's like below

```
create table #temp_table(id int)
insert into #temp_table SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [dbo].ID_TABLE WHERE ID = 'valid'
```